# Cakephp 3 Three Column View based on an Id

Tags: cakephp

This is Cakephp 3.5, So I have three businesses 1, 2, 3. I have a view to show Estimated Revenue From Fees.

On the index page I have a three column Div

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2><?= __('Estimated Revenue From Fees') ?></h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <h4>Business One</h4>
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach ($estimatedRevenueFromCFeesBiz1 as $estimatedRevenueFromFeeBiz1): ?>
                        <li class="actions">
                           <?= $this->Html->link(__( h($estimatedRevenueFromFeeBiz1->year), ['action' => 'view', $estimatedRevenueFromFeeBiz1->id]) ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                 <h4>Business Two</h4>
                 <?php foreach ($estimatedRevenueFromFeesNauBiz2 as $estimatedRevenueFromFeeBiz2): ?>
                        <li class="actions">
                           <?= $this->Html->link(__( h($estimatedRevenueFromFeeNauBiz2->year), ['action' => 'view', $estimatedRevenueFromFeeBiz2->id]) ?>
                        </li>
                 <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                 <h4>Business Three</h4>
                 <?php foreach ($estimatedRevenueFromCourseFeesUa as $estimatedRevenueFromCourseFeeUa): ?>
                        <li class="actions">
                           <?= $this->Html->link(__( h($estimatedRevenueFromFeeBiz3->year), ['action' => 'view', $estimatedRevenueFromFeeBiz3->id]) ?>
                        </li>
                 <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In my controller I've set up like this:

```
 public function index()
        {
            $estimatedRevenueFromFeesBiz1 = $this->EstimatedRevenueFromFeesBiz1->find('list', array( 'conditions' => 'business_id' == 1));
            $estimatedRevenueFromFeesBiz2 = $this->EstimatedRevenueFromFeesBiz2->find('list', array( 'conditions' => 'business_id' == 2));
            $estimatedRevenueFeesBiz3 = $this->EstimatedRevenueFromFeesBiz3->find('list', array( 'conditions' => 'business_id' == 1));
            $this->set(compact('estimatedRevenueFromFeesBiz1', 'estimatedRevenueFromFeesBiz2', 'estimatedRevenueFromFeesBiz3'));
        }
```

I'm getting a Call to a member function find() on boolean 
Error in: ROOT\src\Controller\EstimatedRevenueFromCourseFeesController.php, line 26 which is the

`$estimatedRevenueFromFeesBiz1 = $this->EstimatedRevenueFromFeesBiz1->find('list', array( 'conditions' => 'business_id' == 1)); line.`

Comment: is this `$this->EstimatedRevenueFromFeesBiz1` a Table instance for you to call on `find`? Doesn't look like it

Comment: Yes. EstimatedRevenueFromFees is a Table. with a column named business_id. It is a foreign key for a Business table with the business names.

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe I should just call the table in the controller like normal and do the separation in the view. Not sure what the correct code would be but if I added an if statement around the <li>. So if business_id == 1 do the <li> else continue. Something like that

Comment: If the Table name is `EstimatedRevenueFromFees` why are you calling `find` on `EstimatedRevenueFromFeesBiz1` ?

Comment: I was trying to break them into three arrays based on the business id so that the detail link would be in the correct column under the business name.

Comment: You should look into collections, you could simply group a single resultset by the `business_id` column. **[https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake\Collection\Collection::groupBy](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake\Collection\Collection::groupBy)**

Comment: ndm. Your collections worked great! I used the filter instead of the groupBy. That allowed me three variables to call the foreach method.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I changed the controller back to just calling the whole table:

```
public function index()
        {
            $this->paginate = [
                'contain' => ['Businesses']
            ];
            $estimatedRevenueFromFees = $this->paginate($this->EstimatedRevenueFromFees);
            $this->set(compact('estimatedRevenueFromFees'));
        }
```

I then added a condition into the index.ctp file:

```
        <h4>Business One</h4>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($estimatedRevenueFromFees as $estimatedRevenueFromFee): ?>
                <?php if ($estimatedRevenueFromFee['business_id'] == 1): ?>
                <li class="actions">
                   <?= $this->Html->link(__( h($estimatedRevenueFromFee->year), ['action' => 'view', $estimatedRevenueFromFee->id]) ?>
                </li>
                <?php else: ?>
                <?php   continue; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: this same format was put in under the header Business Two and Three and the == sign was changed to reflect 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on what you said and on your own answer, it looks like what you were trying to do was this:

```
public function index() {
  $estimatedRevenueFromFeesBiz1 = $this->EstimatedRevenueFromFees->find('list', ['conditions' => ['business_id' == 1]]);

  $estimatedRevenueFromFeesBiz2 = $this->EstimatedRevenueFromFees->find('list', ['conditions' => ['business_id' == 2]]);

  $estimatedRevenueFeesBiz3 = $this->EstimatedRevenueFromFees->find('list', ['conditions' => ['business_id' == 1]]);

  $this->set(compact('estimatedRevenueFromFeesBiz1', 'estimatedRevenueFromFeesBiz2', 'estimatedRevenueFromFeesBiz3'));
```

}

What changes is your condition (business_id). But you are always querying over the same table (EstimatedRevenueFromFees).

Bare in mind that in your solution you are paginating. So you might end up having every record in a page with a certain business_id, or whatever combination.

Comment: I tried this one but found that it did not filter with the conditions. I still got the full list. I also there was an error when I used 'list' I had to use 'all'.

Comment: well, `list` returns an array where the index is the primary key and the value is the display key. It's useful for when you want to put the results into a select. I copy/pasted from yours that's why it says `list`